# Athena: How to check number of duplicate elements in arrays of different rows

Tags: sql, hiveql, amazon-athena

My table is on AWS Athena. I am not familiar with SQL or HIVE or Athena in general. I have the following table

```
col_id , col_list
ABC    , [abcde, 123gd, 12345, ...]
B3C    , [bbbbb, ergdg, 12345, ...]
YUT    , [uyteh, bbbbb, 12345, ...]
```

`col_id` is unique and the elements in the array of one single row are also unique.

I need to run a query that count the total number of elements that repeat in different arrays in different rows. In the example above, the array element `12345` shows up in 1st, 2nd, and 3rd rows, and `bbbbb` shows up in 2nd and 3rd rows, so the number of repetitive elements is 2.

The number of rows is not big so I guess the performance is not a concern here.

Could anyone please let me know how to write this query in Athena?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the array and aggregate:

```
select col, count(*)
from t lateral view
     explode(t.col_list) col
group by col
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I got the error "Queries of this type are not supported" when running the query above. Is there another approach?

Comment: After checking this https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html and replace explode with UNNEST. I got the result. But could you please modify your answer to use UNNEST as well? So other ppl won't be confused. Thanks.

Comment: @JeffXi . . . Your question is tagged Hive, not PrestoDB, but I'm glad it worked out.